# Fastlane + Github Actions: Couldn't find gradlew at path

Tags: android, flutter, github-actions, fastlane, gradlew

I'm trying to implement a CI/CD workflow for Flutter using Github Actions and Fastlane. But, when the lane is executing throws the following error:

[image]

I create the Fastlane folder inside the android folder. Like the image
[image]

This is the content of my `Fastfile`:

```
update_fastlane

default_platform(:android)

platform :android do
  desc "Deploy to closed beta track"
  lane :closed_beta do
    begin
      gradle(task: "clean")
      gradle(
        task: "bundle",
        build_type: 'Release'
      )
      upload_to_play_store(
        track: 'Closed beta',
        aab: '../build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab',
        skip_upload_metadata: true,
        skip_upload_images: true,
        skip_upload_screenshots: true,
        release_status: "draft",
        version_code: flutter_version()["version_code"],
      )
    end
  end
end
```

And my GitHub action workflow that allows to make the build and deployment is like below. The `Run Fastlane` step is the error point

```
name: Continuous Delivery to Play Store

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "v*"

jobs:
  # Continuous integration
  build_android:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Setup Java
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 12.x
      - name: Decrypt Android keys
        run: sh ./.github/scripts/decrypt_android_keys.sh
        env:
          ANDROID_KEYS_SECRET_PASSPHRASE: ${{ secrets.ANDROID_KEYS_SECRET_PASSPHRASE }}
      - name: Setup Flutter
        uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
        with:
          flutter-version: 1.22.5
      - name: Install Flutter dependencies
        run: flutter pub get
        # Add build runner commands here if you have any
      - name: Format files
        run: flutter format --set-exit-if-changed .
      - name: Analyze files
        run: flutter analyze .
      - name: Run the tests
        run: flutter test
      - name: Build the APK
        run: flutter build apk
      - name: Upload artifact to Github
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: release-apk
          path: build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk
  # Continuous delivery
  deploy_android:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [build_android]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Setup Java
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 12.x
      - name: Decrypt Android keys
        run: sh ./.github/scripts/decrypt_android_keys.sh
        env:
          ANDROID_KEYS_SECRET_PASSPHRASE: ${{ secrets.ANDROID_KEYS_SECRET_PASSPHRASE }}
      - name: Setup Flutter
        uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
        with:
          flutter-version: 1.22.5
      - name: Install Flutter dependencies
        run: flutter pub get
      - name: Build app bundle
        run: flutter build appbundle
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          ruby-version: 2.6
          bundler-cache: true
      - name: Check file existence
        run: echo find . -name "gradlew"
      - uses: maierj/fastlane-action@v2.0.0
        with:
          lane: closed_beta
          subdirectory: android
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41249497/fastlane-cannot-find-gradlew-file

Comment: have you found the answer to this question?

Comment: Currently not :(

Comment: Hey did you manage to fix this? Noticed boxting is mentioned twice in the gradle path

Comment: @EnzoLizama Did you manage to get a way around this?

Answer (score 2):

Run `flutter build appbundle -v` before other tasks in a lane like this

````
lane :beta do
  sh "flutter build appbundle -v" <- Add this
  upload_to_play_store(
    track: 'beta',
    aab: '../build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab',
    json_key_data: ENV['PLAY_STORE_CONFIG_JSON'],
    )
end```
````

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue and what I found that gradlew is excluded in .gitignore inside /android folder of your flutter project.

While following runs on your local machine, it won't run Github runner:

```
gradle(task: "clean")
gradle(
    task: "bundle",
    build_type: 'Release'
  )
```

Consider deleting lines above from Fastfile as you already do build on Github
behalf here:

> name: Build the APK
>
> run: flutter build apk

Comment: I tried this, it did not work.